# When does $\sum_{i=3}^\infty n^{-1} (\log \log n)^{-r}$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For $r>0$, when does $\sum_{i=3}^\infty n^{-1} (\log \log n)^{-r}$ converge? My guess is $r>1$ (treating $\log \log$ as $\log$). Please give me some hints!

Comment: It may be worth internalizing that $n\log n$ is closer to $n$ than $n^{1\pm\epsilon}$ for any fixed $\epsilon$. This is not precise or rigorous at all, but that understanding can let you look at this series and in a single glance say that it is too close to the harmonic series (regardless of the value of $r$) to be convergent. If you'd like to make that claim precise, Andre's answer goes in that direction.

Comment: @alex.jordan How would you interpret $n(\log n)^2$ then?

Comment: If $\log n<n^\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$, then squaring both sides and recognizing $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $(\log n)^2<n^\epsilon$ too. I am of course, still being imprecise and only conveying a feeling for expressions like these.

Comment: @alex.jordan I was trying to let you realise that while your comments apply to both $n(\log n)$ and $n(\log n)^2$, these two behave rather differently (the latter give a convergent series, while the former doesn't).

Comment: Oh the perils of being imprecise. Point well made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never.  You probably know that $\sum \frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges. If you have not done it yet, it can be done using the Integral Test.

We need only consider positive $r$ (why?).

For positive $r$, note that in the long run $(\log\log n)^r \lt \log n$ (why?). So by Comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n\log n}$ our series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Condensation test (why is it possible to use it?) and comparison test:

$$\frac{2^n}{2^n\log^r(\log 2^n)}=\frac1{\left(\log n+\log2\right)^r}\ge\frac1{2^r\log^rn}$$

Finally, just use that $\,\forall\,\epsilon >0\;,\;\;\log n\le n^\epsilon\;$ (for example for $\,\epsilon=\frac1r\;$...) and apply the comparison test to show divergence